# В чем разница между вдвоем и на двоих?

Tags: грамматика, словарь

А также втроем / на троих и др.

Недавно я заметил, что я часто употребляю первую форму, которая приходит в голову, не думая о том, считается ли это ошибкой.

Мне, изучающему русский, непонятно, чем они различаются в данных случаях:

> Я раньше и не думал, что у нас /
>   на двоих с тобой одно лишь дыхание

и

> Теченье [реки] несло нас уже вдвоем

Оба примера из песен Наутилус.
Мне кажется, что в обоих случаях, можно перевести как «the two [of us] together» .

Comment: Я не знал которую употреблять в этих случаях (а теперь все ясно): играть в карты, ехать в машине, и гулять в группе.

Comment: Кстати, почему этот downvote ?

Comment: @Nika вы и правда употребляете форму "на двоих" и "вдвоём" одинаково часто? То есть например "Давай сделаем это на двоих" вместо "вдвоём"?

Comment: Я не родной носитель русского, а иностранец, изучающий русский. Я же сказал, что я сомневаюсь в том, можно ли употреблять обе формы одинаково. Очевидно, что русский знал бы это.

Comment: @Nika, вы большой молодец, потому что по тому, как ваш вопрос задан, не сразу можно понять, что вы не носитель. Что касается минусования (down-votes), то не обращайте на это слишком много внимания - просто данный конкретный вопрос показался сообществу не самым универсально полезным

Comment: @Nika Я не голосовал против вашего вопроса, но мне кажется что это из-за того что вы не привели примеров, хотя это сделать не трудно. Вопрос получился очень широким и абстрактным. Кстати, вы всегда можете редактировать собственные вопросы и ответы. Если вы добавите примеры в свой вопрос, то те кто голосовал "против" смогут проголосовать "за" или отменить свой голос.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Наречия вдвоём, втроём, вчетверо́м, впятеро́м, вшестеро́м, всемеро́м употребляются, когда мы говорим о каком-либо совместном действии:

> Мы вдвоём справимся с трудной работой.
>
> Они пришли в ресторан втроём.

«На двои́х», «на трои́х», «на четверы́х» и т. д. являются собирательными числительными, употребленными в винительном падеже. Они не обозначают совместного действия, а значат «на двух человек», «на трёх человек» и т. д.

> Давай закажем столик на четверых.
>
> «Нам с тобой на двоих было неба мало».
>
> Сообразим на троих!

Comment: В оборотах типа _нам на двоих хватит_ вместо _на двоих_ вполне можно сказать _вдвоем_. Более случаев взаимозаменяемости я сейчас припомнить не могу.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov "Нам двоим хватит", не "вдвоем".

Comment: @Artemix При чем здесь _двоим_? Про эту форму вопрос не стоял. Все три варианта находимы в употреблении, в порядке убывания частоты: _нам на двоих хватит_, _нам двоим хватит_, _нам вдвоем хватит_. Более чем допускаю, что последний можно назвать «не литературным», но он существует.

Comment: Юлия, спасибо за объяснение. А как насчет слова играть? В гугле находится столько же примеров «играть вдвоем», сколько и «играть на двоих».

Comment: @Nika "играть на двоих" - не правильно. "Играть вдвоем" говорят когда играют два человека. "Играть вдвоем против пятерых" - команда из двух игроков играет против команды из пятерых игроков. "Игра на двоих" - игра, в которой могут принимать участие двое игроков (обычно один играет против другого - крестики-нолики, шахматы, шашки, "морской бой" и т.д.).

Comment: Ясно, Артемикс )